# an inequality involving total variation

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the following statement:

> $F,G$ are increasing right continuous functions and $\alpha$ is a  right  continuous function satisfies:
>   $$|\alpha(t)-\alpha(s)|^2\le (F(t)-F(s))(G(t)-G(s))$$
>   let $\tilde{\alpha}$ be the total variation function of $\alpha$, i.e. $\tilde{\alpha}(t)=V_0^t(\alpha)$, then 
>   $$|\tilde\alpha(t)-\tilde\alpha(s)|^2\le (F(t)-F(s))(G(t)-G(s))$$

first take partitions $\Pi_n:s=t_0\le t_1\le\cdots\le t_n=t$, then $$\begin{split}&\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha(t_{i})-\alpha(t_{i-1})|\right)^2\\\le &n\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha(t_{i})-\alpha(t_{i-1})|^2\\\le &n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1}))(G(t_i)-G(t_{i-1}))\\\le &n(F(t)-F(s))(G(t)-G(s))\end{split}$$

then I want to take the supreme, but the coefficient $n$ makes it impossible, how to deal with it? Thanks in advance.

---

I might find the solution:
$$\begin{split}&\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha(t_{i})-\alpha(t_{i-1})|\\\le &\sum_{i=1}^{n}(F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1}))^{1/2}(G(t_i)-G(t_{i-1}))^{1/2}\\\le &\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}G(t_i)-G(t_{i-1})\right)^{1/2}\\=&(F(t)-F(s))^{1/2}(G(t)-G(s))^{1/2}\end{split}$$
since the inequality holds for all partitions, take the supreme to get:
$$|\tilde\alpha(t)-\tilde\alpha(s)|\le (F(t)-F(s))^{1/2}(G(t)-G(s))^{1/2}$$

Comment: This notation is confusing to me. Usually I see total variation of a function over an interval $(a,b)$ denoted $V_a^b (f)$. If your interval is $(s,t)$ what does the dependency of $s$ or $t$ mean in $\tilde\alpha(t)$ or $\tilde\alpha(s)$?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 if $f$ is defined on $[0,t]$, then $\forall s<t$, we can define $V_0^s(f)$, then define $\tilde{\alpha}(s)=V_0^s (\alpha)$